# Try-Catch not handling errors with an https.get request in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, error-handling, try-catch

I have an https.get request in Node for which I need to handle the errors - preferably in a try-catch block. For instance, when the url is incorrect

I have tried wrapping the https.get block in a try catch and I have tried handling with res.on('error'). It seems as if in both instances the error doesn't reach the error handling block.

```
const https = require('https');

const hitApi = () => {

    const options = {
        "hostname": "api.kanye.rest"
    };

    try {
        https.get(options, res => {

            let body = '';


            res.on('data', data => {
                body += data;
            });

            res.on('end', () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                console.dir(body);
            });

        });

    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

hitApi();
```

If I change the url to a nonexistent API (e.g. api.kaye.rest) I would expect to see a handled e.rror response. Instead I see 'Unhandled error event'

Comment: use `.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e);
});` https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why try...catch.. fails is that it is meant for handling **synchronous** errors. `https.get()` is **asynchronous** and cannot be handled with a usual try..catch..

Use `req.on('error',function(e){});` to handle the error. Like so:

```
var https = require('https');

var options = {
  hostname: 'encrypted.google.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
  console.log("headers: ", res.headers);

  res.on('data', function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d);
  });
});
req.end();
// Error handled here.
req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
});
```

You can read more about the same in the documentation over [here](https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/https/#httpsgetoptions-callback)

Comment: I had it like this but it somehow didn't catch an error and just hung itself up instead. I switched to using axios, which correctly caught the request error. I guess axios is so widely used because https.get is error prone due to lots of required config. Axios is even suggested by node here: https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs